# Split column values into multiple columns with CREATE VIEW

Tags: mysql, sql, create-view

With a MySQL query, how can I take a table like in Example A:

```
Example A
+------+---------------+----------+
| id   | value         | class    |
+------+---------------+----------+
| 1    | 33.00         | total    |
| 1    | 12.00         | shipping |
| 2    | 45.00         | total    |
| 2    | 15.00         | shipping |
+------+---------------+----------+
```

And create a view like Example B?

```
Example B
+------+---------------+---------------+
| id   | value_total   | value_shipping|
+------+---------------+---------------+
| 1    | 33.00         | 12.00         |
| 2    | 45.00         | 15.00         |
+------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Quick question, is the column id a primary key? They are duplicate. I think your schema is at fault here. Should be id:1, shipping: 12, total: 33 for the first entry. Rather than having the same id. Read up on http://www.tonymarston.co.uk/php-mysql/database-design.html#relational.db

Comment: it is not a primary key, this is just a sample of a part of a table.

Comment: If you can give the exact table schema it would be nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `SUM()` function for that:

```
SELECT id
,SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'total' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS value_total
,SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'shipping' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS value_shipping
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY id;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25732/2)

If you have unknown number of *class* then try this Dynamic query

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when class = ''',
      class,
      ''' then value else 0 end) AS `value_',
      class, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Table1;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, ', @sql, '
                  FROM Table1 
                  GROUP BY id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID ║ VALUE_TOTAL ║ VALUE_SHIPPING ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════════╣
║  1 ║          33 ║             12 ║
║  2 ║          45 ║             15 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25732/1)

Comment: I think SUM might be the better route, it doesn't ignore multiple values of the same id like MAX. :) Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  select id , 
  max(case when class = 'total' then value end) as value_total
 , max(case when class = 'shipping' then value end) as value_shipping
  from Table1
  group by id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0598a/3)

Comment: `MAX()` function won't work if you have multiple value for same id. E.g. see [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/862a5/1).

Comment: Just need to add: CREATE VIEW view_name AS

Comment: I think this works for me as each id only has one value for shipping or total in my table, correct me if I'm wrong?