# select from multiple tables, same database case conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case

I have a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397666/split-column-values-into-multiple-columns-with-create-view), but with a little bit more twist and pertaining to sql server 2k8r2.
Database has 3 tables. sites, users, users_sites. I need to get a list of emailaddresses from users table plus 2 columns indicating what sites they're a member. users could be either a member of 1, 2 or none(most likely inactive).

here is my script but i keep getting a 2 rows for each email but my aim is to get 3 columns of email, site1 member as 1 or site2 member as 0 or if members of both, 1,1 and if none 0,0

```
+----------+-------+-------+
|emailAddy | site1 | site2 |
+------+-----------+-------+
|1@test.co | 0     | 1     |
|1@test.co | 1     | 0     |
|2@test.jp | 1     | 1     |
|2@test.jp | 1     | 1     |
+----------+-------+-------+


SELECT distinct emailaddress
,CASE WHEN cast(siteid AS varchar(max))= '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS site1
,CASE WHEN cast(siteid AS varchar(max))= '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS site2
FROM Users, Users_Sites 
GROUP BY emailaddress,siteID
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of the implicit `JOIN` (replace it with an explicit `JOIN` as shown below), as it is you've got no criteria and are just joining each record to every record in the other table.

Then just wrap your conditionals in an aggregate:

```
SELECT emailaddress
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN cast(siteid AS varchar(max))= '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS site1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN cast(siteid AS varchar(max))= '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS site2
FROM Users u
JOIN Users_Sites us
   ON u.user_id = us.user_id  --No idea what your actual join criteria should be.
GROUP BY emailaddress
```

Also don't need `DISTINCT` when using `GROUP BY`, and `siteid` shouldn't be in your `GROUP BY` if you don't want one record returned per `siteid`.

Edit, didn't even see your implicit `JOIN`

Comment: No connection between two tables will generate a full cross join cartesian product.

Comment: removed downvote, but if first table is indeed table of users, then join would have to be on something user related, like `userId`

Comment: @CharlesBretana  thanks very much guys. First off, i forgot to mention that im no sql expert, im always learning and didnt comprehend the joining of tables with same db properly. Both your inputs helped me understand better. thanks again.

Comment: @shilezi,  Rather than think of it as a join, think of it as a product (meaning *every* possible combination of rows in one table with rows in the other table) with a `predicate` condition or restriction on what rows should be included.  Without any predicate condition, every combination will get included... so if one table has 11 rows and the other has 7, the result will have 77 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select u.emailAddress,
   case when exists(Select * from Users_Sites 
                    Where SiteId = 1 
                      And UserId = u.UserId) 
        then 'x' End Site1,
   case when exists(Select * from Users_Sites 
                    Where SiteId = 2 
                      And UserId = u.UserId) 
        then 'x' End Site2
From users u
```

Comment: both answers are correct, wish i could mark both as correct though.